Challenges in translating a document using Azure

Addition of the words YES and NO to Korean documents without association with the document's context.
enter image description here

2.Encounters challenges in precisely translating documents containing numbered lines.
enter image description here
3.Texts with words overlapping other words
enter image description here
4.Translates sentences without spaces between words in Japanese documents.
enter image description here
5.Texts in tables may be translated as if they were one forthright statement instead of individual cells
enter image description here
The steps taken and the results are attached.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is there an email ID where I can send the screenshots so that it would make more sense?
